# GNU Radio version

Tags: c++, gnuradio

How do I find out the version of GNU Radio that I have installed?

I would like the use their messaging libraries, but they are available on newer versions of gnuradio only and for some reason I'm getting a compilation error when I try to use the following code:

```
message_port_register_out(pmt::mp("out_message"));
```

I get the following error on compilation:

```
error: ‘message_port_register_out’ was not declared in this scope
```

It's supposed to be part of the `gr_basic_block`, which all blocks inherit from, but it's not compiling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the version number using python.

```
from gnuradio import gr
gr.version()
```

Answer (score 8):

If you installed the complete package - not only the library - in a terminal window:

```
$ gnuradio-companion --version

GNU Radio Companion 3.7.2.1
```

or

```
$ gnuradio-config-info --version
3.7.2.1
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any distribution that would offer the GNU Radio library without gnuradio-config-info, but I do believe that such exists. Can you enlighten me on where that happens?

Comment: Wow, this was a year ago! I believe I meant that gnuradio-companion might not always be available. That's what the reply said too: The idea is that the library is always available, but not always grc. It's been a while, but I believe grc *can* be disabled from `configure`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr__basic__block.html), message_port_register_out is a member of gr_basic_block. Based on the compilation error you have posted and the code snippet, I'd assume you need an instance to work with. It's hard to tell without more context however.

Comment: Well, what about the first part of the question.  How do I find out the version of gnuradio i have installed?

Comment: It's written in the constructor of a source block.

Comment: Not knowing much about your particular system setup, the best I could offer is a find command. Something like `find /usr/lib -name 'lib*radio*` - this should yield you some result like libgnuradiosomething.so.3.61 or something similar. Sorry I can't be more precise here. Also check /usr/local/lib